# Need Excel macro code for my requirements

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 columns in excel. 
I want to perform the below scenario.
I want a macro button which can assign value to the 3rd column based on the lookup value of 1st column 
like:

- when i click the button, it should ask for "value(customer no.)"
- after entering the value, it should ask for "Value(Amount)"
- after entering the value, it should find the "Value(customer no.)" in the first column and assign the "Value(amount)" correspondingly in the 3rd column  this actions happens repeatedly for multiple values.

My Data :

```
Customer No. |  Customer Name |  Amount
_____________|________________|__________
      1      |  Ramesh        |
      2      |  Kumar         |
      3      |  Dinesh        |
      4      |  Praveen       |
      5      |  Anand         |
```

i used the following code on a button to insert data but it cannot read Customer No. it reads only the row number

```
Sub Rectangle2()  
    iText = InputBox("Enter Amount")  
    iRow = InputBox("Enter Number")  

    Cells(iRow, 3).Value = iText  
End Sub
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverFlow. This site is not really a "Give me code for this" site, but more of a "Help me find my problem". What you want to achieve is fairly easy. Try put some code together and post it in your Question. This will also prevent down votes

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub Rectangle2()  
    Dim f As Range

    iText = InputBox("Enter Amount")  
    iRow = InputBox("Enter Number") 

    Set f = Activesheet.Columns(1).find(What:=iRow, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) 
    If Not f Is Nothing then
        f.offset(0, 2).Value = iText
    End If  
End Sub
```